# Execute code on TrackBar scroll stop in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project in Windows Forms, in which I need to execute some code once the scrolling of the TrackBar has stopped, preferably without timers. I have thought about the `MouseUp`-event, but this would not work with changing the value using the arrow-keys.

Is there any other way to do this, perhaps using the built-in `EventArgs e` that gets passed to the event-handler.

My current code for the event:

```
private void TrBrSize_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScrollEventArgs temp = e as ScrollEventArgs; // Trying to unpack the EventArgs
    
    if (temp == ScrollEventType.EndScroll) // Check if the unpacked value is of type EndScroll
    {
        *** other code ***
    }
}
```

I attempted to unpack the `EventArgs` from the event as `ScrollEventArgs`, in order to check if the type of event is `EndScroll`, but this does not work and instead crashes the program because the unpacking returns `Null`.

Comment: You'll have to throw that code away, it can't work.  An alternative is hard to come by when you don't explain why you need this.

Comment: Ah okay. I need it as the slider changes the size of a window, but it can't update the size all the time, as then the slider moves and weird stuff happens...